# How to Pass Variable to PDF in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, ruby-on-rails-plugins, prawn

This questions is somewhat related to this question [Prawn + Prawnto Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402723/prawn-prawnto-issue/11403466#11403466). I've noticed  that if something is really hard to do in rails, you're probably doing it wrong.

I have prawnto and prawn installed, and if I go to `http://localhost:3000/holders/1.pdf` I get exactly the PDF I want except for I have a variable `count` that is manually set in the pdf currently that I need to pass to each pdf as it is created.

My approach was to create a generate action that was supposed to generate the pdf, but I can't seem to get that to work. Prawnto's documentation is down.

What is the easiest way to do this using prawn + prawnto? Is my generate action the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't using a plain @ variable work? I do this all the time.

```
# controller
def show
  @count = 55
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf { prawnto }
  end
end

# show.pdf.prawn
pdf.text @count
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. What I was trying to do is have a generate.pdf.prawn and then have the show view pass the count variable to the generate controller and have that generate the pdf. I was over complicating it.